# Handling status message upon submitting asp mvc form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been using asp MVC model state error when handling errors.
currently, I was using temp data as you see below:

```
TempData["message"] = "Successfully Added New Data.";
```

and rendered in all my views with forms.

I just want to ask any best practice that can be used when it comes to handling success message/status.

TIA!

Comment: `viewbag` is best for that

Answer (score 1):

If you are redirecting to another view you can use `TempData` collection. If you are staying on the same view, I would return current view with a flag in the model and then render it base on the value or just use `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the error or success message in the model you sent to the view.

Something like that:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CityDetails()
{
    MyModel MyModel = new MyModel();
    MyModel.Message = "Successfully Added New Data.";
    return View(MyModel);
}
```